# How to transfer a value from inputs to array?

Tags: javascript

I want to transfer the value from three inputs:  "name", "counter" and  "price" to the array "products" that I then display in the table. But when I add them using the `buttAdd.addEventListener` handler, the new elements are not displayed in the table Help fix this

```js
//Product Creation Class
class Product {
    constructor(name, count, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
// Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
    constructor(products) {
        this.products = [];
    }

    //method for adding a product
    addProduct(newProduct) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }

    show() {
        const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#shop .data");
        for (let i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            const e = rows.item(i);
            e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
        }
        const table = document.getElementById("shop");
        for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
            //create table
            table.innerHTML += `<tr class="data"><td>${this.products[i].name}</td>
    <td>${this.products[i].price}</td>
    <td>${this.products[i].count}</td></tr>`;
        }
    }
}
const formAdd = document.forms[0];
const inputsAdd = formAdd.elements;
const buttAdd = formAdd.elements[3];
buttAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        shop.addProduct(inputsAdd[i].value);
    }
    shop.show();
}, false);
let shop = new Shop();
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 2000));
shop.show();
```

```html
  <form id="addForm">
            <label for="name" >Name of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="name" class="input-product">
            <label for="price">Price of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="price" class="input-product">
            <label for="count">Count of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="count" class="input-product">
            <button id="add">Add</button>
        </form>
  <table id="shop">
        <caption>Products that are available in the store</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <th id="filter">Price:</th>
            <th>Count:</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Below are the errors in your code.**

1. Your for loop inside `buttAdd.addEventListener` is not correct.condition `<=3` will iterate 4 time while input fields are only 3.
2. `shop.addProduct(inputsAdd[i].value);` is wrong because `addProduct` method of `shop` class required `Product` class object so you need to create new `Product class` object and set the values of input through `constructor`.

**This is the correct way:**

```
shop.addProduct(new Product(inputsAdd[0].value,inputsAdd[1].value,inputsAdd[2].value));
```

***Here is the running snippet***

```js
//Product Creation Class
class Product {
    constructor(name, count, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
// Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
    constructor(products) {
        this.products = [];
    }

    //method for adding a product
    addProduct(newProduct) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }

    show() {
        const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#shop .data");
        for (let i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            const e = rows.item(i);
            e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
        }
        const table = document.getElementById("shop");
        for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
            //create table
            table.innerHTML += `<tr class="data"><td>${this.products[i].name}</td>
    <td>${this.products[i].price}</td>
    <td>${this.products[i].count}</td></tr>`;
        }
    }
}
   

     const formAdd = document.forms[0];
    
        const inputsAdd = formAdd.elements;
      
        const buttAdd = formAdd.elements[3];
    
        //console.log(buttAdd);
      
        buttAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    shop.addProduct(new Product(inputsAdd[0].value,parseInt(inputsAdd[1].value),inputsAdd[2].value));
            shop.show();
  
}, false);
        let shop = new Shop();
        shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 2000));
        shop.show();
```

```html
  <form id="addForm">
            <label for="name" >Name of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="name" class="input-product">
            <label for="price">Price of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="price" class="input-product">
            <label for="count">Count of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="count" class="input-product">
            <button id="add">Add</button>
        </form>
  <table id="shop">
        <caption>Products that are available in the store</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <th id="filter">Price:</th>
            <th>Count:</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your addProduct() method takes in a Product object as input, but in click listener you are passing form field input values without forming a object

```js
//Product Creation Class
class Product {
    constructor(name, count, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
// Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
    constructor(products) {
        this.products = [];
    }

    //method for adding a product
    addProduct(newProduct) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }

    show() {
        const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#shop .data");
        for (let i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            const e = rows.item(i);
            e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
        }
        const table = document.getElementById("shop");
        for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
            //create table
            table.innerHTML += `<tr class="data"><td>${this.products[i].name}</td>
    <td>${this.products[i].price}</td>
    <td>${this.products[i].count}</td></tr>`;
        }
    }
}
const formAdd = document.forms[0];
const inputsAdd = formAdd.elements;
const buttAdd = formAdd.elements[3];
buttAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let tempProduct = new 
Product(inputsAdd[0].value,parseInt(inputsAdd[1].value),parseInt(inputsAdd[2].value));
        
    shop.addProduct(tempProduct);
    shop.show();
}, false);
let shop = new Shop();
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 2000));
shop.show();
```

```html
  <form id="addForm">
            <label for="name" >Name of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="name" class="input-product">
            <label for="price">Price of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="price" class="input-product">
            <label for="count">Count of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="count" class="input-product">
            <button id="add">Add</button>
        </form>
  <table id="shop">
        <caption>Products that are available in the store</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <th id="filter">Price:</th>
            <th>Count:</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```